# Dark Mode - Items in Windows Explorer with Black Font

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, dark-mode

I have Dark Mode Enabled on Windows 10.

In Windows Explorer, in just one Folder, the Items (SubFolder, Files, etc)  are showing displayed with a black font.
All other folders (even in subfolders of the one affected) are showed with a white font.

Any idea on how to fix that?

[image: Explorer]

Comment: Idea: Move all the contents of this folder to a new folder, verify that they are displayed correctly, then replace the old folder by the new one.

Comment: Is the folder customized with a desktop.ini file? If you add the attributes column to the affected folder's *parent* folder, does the affected folder have it's `ReadOnly` attribute set?

Comment: @harrymc have tried that already with no luck. i believe the setting is somewhere in the registry, however i search all of the registry for the parent path for any indications and no luck.

Comment: @KeithMiller there's no desktop.ini in the parent / affected folder. adding a column in the parent folder doesn't affect the child folder. read only attribute is set on the parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings> Personalization> Themes and make sure the color is set to Automatic.

We will need to access the registry editor Windows via the command "regedit" that we type after pressing the key combination "Win + R". Once in this section, we go to the path: "HKEY_CURRENT_USERControl PanelColors".

So in the right panel we have to look for an entry called "WindowText", which will be one of the last, and if we click on it twice we will probably find that its value is "0 0 0", which is this translates into black if we speak in terms of RGB . Therefore, what we recommend is to change these three values ​​to "130 130 130" and we can close the editor and restart the computer.

https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/fix-black-text-in-file-explorer-location-bar-on-windows-10-dark-mode/

If that does not work, follow the instructions here:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-black-text-with-dark-theme/72b77bc4-23bc-4053-a3c4-831eaa152d6c

Comment: thanks, but I have this only in one folder, the links are for general problems with font color.